# Django apostrophe escaping change

Tags: html, django, encoding

While upgrading Django I noticed that the html escape function used to translate an apostrophe into `&#39;` whereas it now translates it into `&#x27;`. I understand the old value is the HTML code and the new value is the hex code. The change seems to have come about because Django used to do the translation itself but now hands it off to python's html module.
My question is, are these functionally equivalent? Are there any case where I would need to worry about this change?
Also, in case I am not asking the right questions, can anyone direct me to what I should read to understand why these 2 types of codes exist and how they are used?